# != and !== both not always working?

Tags: templates

In multiple wp templates i use `!==` in a IF statement, but i found that this code is not working in 1 template. I changed it to `!=` and now it works. My question is are both the same if statements and why won't `!==` work in this particular template?

Any ideas on this?

Should i change all `!==` to `!=` ?

The particular if statement that i am talking about is (so !== is not working in the statement below but != is)

```
$homefeatured = get_post_meta( $listing->ID, 'featured-home', true );
 $catfeatured = get_post_meta( $listing->ID, 'featured-cat', true );    
if (!empty($plans) && $plan['ID'] != 104 || $plan['ID'] ==104 && $homefeatured !=1 ||  $plan['ID'] ==104 && $catfeatured !=1)
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not really a Wordpress issue, but pure PHP.

- `!=`  compares two value and return true when the two values are not like the other. `0 != '0'`  will return false because the values are like each other, the one being an integer value `0` and the other a string value of `0`
- `!==` compare two values and return true if two values are not identical. `0 != '0'` will return true because the two value are not identical. `0` is an integer and `'0'` is string, so they are clearly not identical. It it the same as an apple, a green apple is not identical to a red apple because of colour

In any condition you need to know what the value will be you need to do a comparison. Ideally you would want to do strict comparisons, that is `!==` and `===`, but for this to work you would need know exactly what you value would have to be and of what kind.

As I showed already, `0` can be a string or an integer. If you are going to accept `0` as an integer or a string, then you should use less strict rules (*`!=` or `==`*). If you just need to accept `0` as an integer **OR** a string, then you should use strict rules (*`!==` or `===`*)

### EDIT

For stict rules, you can always cast a value to what you need it to be before comparison, like you can cast a string value of `0` to an integer and then do a strick compare between the two values, so in short, `0 !== (int) '0'` should return false as the values would be identical as `'0'` will become `0` when being cast to an integer value